# Is it possible to reuse `intl` context from IntlProvider?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-intl, formatjs

I have a component (popup) that renders outside of the tree (aka portal), therefore losing the context of `IntlProvider`:

```
<IntlProvider locale="en">
    <App />
</IntlProvider>
// * <- renders here
```

Redux solves the same issue by allowing to pass store instance as a prop for the component:

```
import store from "./store";

const Component = () => <Popup store={store} />;
```

Is there a similar approach I can use for ReactIntl?

Comment: You can certainly pass the `intl` object to your popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [injectIntl](https://github.com/yahoo/react-intl/wiki/API#injectintl) HOC with injects `intl` into your component.

Simply change you code from:

```
const Component = () => <Popup ... />
```

to:

```
import { injectIntl  } from 'react-intl';
const Component = ({ intl }) => <Popup intl={intl} />
export default injectIntl(Component)
```

Comment: I think that for `injectIntl` to work, the exported component will still need to be within the component hierarchy under `IntlProvider`.

Answer (score -1):

if you dont want to wrap your component into HOC, useIntl hook is good too :)

Comment: While you somewhat answer this question, you should add working code example to your answer. Read [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)!?